# How to override an async method in C++ Cli?

Tags: async-await, overriding, c++-cli

I want to create something for my .NET project.
I write it in C++ Cli because this is something that I can't do in C#.
I need to create a class that extends `System::IO::TextWriter`.
When I try to override the methods with the `async` identifier I get an error.
Because in C++ there is no keyword like C# `async` keyword that I could find, I have no way to override it as an `async` method.
How do I do that?

Comment: Why are you using C++/CLI rather than C#?

Comment: No support for async in C++/CLI.  Not a problem here, trying to use it is not correct.  The async methods in TextWriter that you *might* consider overriding are not declared async, they return `Task`.  As behooves a class that supports using the async keyword in the client code.  Do keep in mind that it is quite unlikely that you'll want to override them, the base class methods already get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

`async` is an implementation detail, not part of the method signature.

Make sure the return type (derived from `Task<>`) matches, and the override will be accepted.  You can use a `TaskCompletionSource` or `Task.FromResult` to create the returned task.